# CSS issue for internet explorer 9 and 10

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9, internet-explorer-10

I am implementing a simple tab like structure. Where when you click tab it will open some content.
The issue is that when I click first tab the second and third one moves, ideally they should not.
For all latest version i am using flex so the issue is only IE9 and IE10 specific which does not support flexbox.

```css
.tab {
    background: #eee;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 10px 15px 10px 20px;
    display: inline-block;
}

.tab-radio:checked + .tab {
    background: #000000;
    color: #ffffff;
}

.tab-radio {
    display: none;
}

.tab-content {
    display: none;
    width: 100%;
}

.tab-radio:checked + label + .tab-content {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="accordion">
    <!-- "For" should point to the input so that we can check the radio using the label. -->
    <input id="1" class="tab-radio" name="tab-choice" type="radio"/>
    <label class="tab" for="1">title 1</label>
    <div class="tab-content">
      <h4>Heading 1</h4>
      Notice that we’ve renamed the variable product to products, and we’ve changed the type to Product[].
    </div>
    <input id="2" class="tab-radio" name="tab-choice" type="radio"/>
    <label class="tab" for="2"> title 2 which is really long</label>
    <div class="tab-content">
      <h4>Heading 2</h4>
      Now that we have our top-level application component, let’s write the ProductsList component,   
    </div>
    <input id="3" class="tab-radio" name="tab-choice" type="radio"/>
    <label class="tab" for="3">title 3</label>
    <div class="tab-content">
      <h4>Heading 3</h4>
      Why is that wrong? Well, because in the case where your browser loads that template before Angular has run,
     
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Can you show how is the normal css? For the others versions

Comment: if i add the other CSS, u will have to switch browser to IE9 to see its effects :) that would be counter productive no ?

Comment: No, no, I just wanna see how it should be like

Comment: Do you want CSS only?

Comment: @hungerstar CSS/HTML changes are all welcomed. doing it with javascript seems redundant.

Comment: JS wouldn't be _"redundant"_. Maybe you were looking for a word like _extraneous_. I only ask because almost all  tabbed content behaviors use JS. While it adds an extra layer (a very small one at that) it allows you to be much more flexible in how you organize your markup and selectors.

Comment: @hungerstar ah yes extraneous. I would like to avoid javascript but obv if there is no other alternative i will use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `float` and negative margin to position the tabs different from the content

```css
.tab {
  background: #eee;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 10px 15px 10px 20px;
  float: left;
}

.tab-radio:checked + .tab {
  background: #000000;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.tab-radio {
  display: none;
}

.tab-content {
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
  float: right;
  margin : 2.5em 0 0 -100%;
}

.tab-radio:checked + label + .tab-content {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="accordion">
  <!-- "For" should point to the input so that we can check the radio using the label. -->
  <input id="1" class="tab-radio" name="tab-choice" type="radio" />
  <label class="tab" for="1">title 1</label>
  <div class="tab-content">
    <h4>Heading 1</h4> Notice that we’ve renamed the variable product to products, and we’ve changed the type to Product[].
  </div>
  <input id="2" class="tab-radio" name="tab-choice" type="radio" />
  <label class="tab" for="2"> title 2 which is really long</label>
  <div class="tab-content">
    <h4>Heading 2</h4> Now that we have our top-level application component, let’s write the ProductsList component,
  </div>
  <input id="3" class="tab-radio" name="tab-choice" type="radio" />
  <label class="tab" for="3">title 3</label>
  <div class="tab-content">
    <h4>Heading 3</h4> Why is that wrong? Well, because in the case where your browser loads that template before Angular has run,

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Avoid negative margin

Comment: @SpaceDogCS why?

Comment: It is a bad practice

Comment: @SpaceDogCS it's a valid approach, nothing wrong with it. If it's bad practice, provide an intelligent reason as to why.

Comment: instead of that you can use position

Comment: @SpaceDogCS Instead of what, negative margin? What `position` value? And why would that be better that isn't just your opinion - back it up with an intelligent reason.

Answer (score 0):

You're using accordion and it's not for 'tabs' like bootstrap tabs.

```css
.tab {
    background: #eee;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 10px 15px 10px 20px;
    display: inline-block;
}

.tab-radio:checked + .tab {
    background: #000000;
    color: #ffffff;
}

.tab-radio {
    display: none;
}

.tab-content {
    display: none;
    width: 100%;
}

.tab-radio:checked + label + .tab-content {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="accordion">
    <!-- "For" should point to the input so that we can check the radio using the label. -->
    <input id="1" class="tab-radio" name="tab-choice" type="radio"/>
    <label class="tab" for="1">title 1</label>
    <div class="tab-content">
      <h4>Heading 1</h4>
      Notice that we’ve renamed the variable product to products, and we’ve changed the type to Product[].
    </div> <Br>
    <input id="2" class="tab-radio" name="tab-choice" type="radio"/>
    <label class="tab" for="2"> title 2 which is really long</label>
    <div class="tab-content">
      <h4>Heading 2</h4>
      Now that we have our top-level application component, let’s write the ProductsList component,   
    </div> <br>
    <input id="3" class="tab-radio" name="tab-choice" type="radio"/>
    <label class="tab" for="3">title 3</label>
    <div class="tab-content">
      <h4>Heading 3</h4>
      Why is that wrong? Well, because in the case where your browser loads that template before Angular has run,
     
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Don't use tag br for that, you can do this with css

Comment: I dont want it to be accordion. it was suppose to be inline tabs.
it will shift to accordion for small screen but that is completely a different thing.

Answer (score 0):

I know you're probably looking for a CSS only solution but I thought I'd throw in a JS example demonstrating how easy it can be to implement. Plus there's the added bonus of not having to have more restrictive markup relationships.

I'm using `data-` attributes to map a tab to it's content and visa versa. The tab and content are joined by assigning the same value in the `data-content` and `data-tab` attributes.

```js
var $tabs = $( '.tabs li' ),
    $content = $( '.tab-content' );
    
$tabs.on( 'click', function ( e ) {
  
  var $this = $( this );

  $tabs.removeClass( 'active' );
  $content.removeClass( 'active' );
  
  $this.addClass( 'active' );
  $( '[data-tab="' + $this.data( 'content' ) + '"]' ).addClass( 'active' );
  
} );
```

```css
.tabs,
.tabs li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.tabs li {
  display: inline;
  padding: 10px 15px 10px 20px;
  background-color: #EEE;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.tabs li.active {
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
}

.tab-content {
  display: none;
}

.tab-content.active {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="accordion">

  <ul class="tabs">
    <li data-content="1">Title 1</li>
    <li data-content="2">Title 2 which is really long</li>
    <li data-content="3">Title 3</li>
  </ul>
  
  <div class="tab-content" data-tab="1">
    
    <h4>Heading 1</h4>
    <p>
      Notice that we’ve renamed the variable product to products, and we’ve changed the type to Product[].
    </p>
    
  </div>
  
  <div class="tab-content" data-tab="2">
    
    <h4>Heading 2</h4>
    <p>
      Now that we have our top-level application component, let’s write the ProductsList component,
    </p>
    
  </div>
  
  <div class="tab-content" data-tab="3">
    
    <h4>Heading 3</h4>
    <p>
      Why is that wrong? Well, because in the case where your browser loads that template before Angular has run,
    </p>
    
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Comment: I thought in that, but I don't know if he'll have some content under it

Comment: sadly i cant use absolute positions. that was my first guess too.

Comment: Updated with JS solution.